# test $x,%dil vs. test $x,%edi

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86-64, att, micro-optimization

I want to test a bit in a register, namely the second lowest one in `%rdi`.
Naively I would write `test $2, %edi` (or `and $2, %edi` -- I don't know if `and`ing would be better -- the rest of the register is irrelevant at this point).

I checked what clang and gcc generate (for a dummy `void TEST(long X){ if(X&2) abort(); }`), and while they seem similarly split on `test` vs `and`, they both surprised me by both agreeing to address the register via `%dil`, not `%edi`.

What might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both ways have equal performance except for code-size; reading a low-8-bit partial register never has any penalty, unlike `test $2, %bh` for example; reading high-8 registers has [extra latency on Haswell and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to) but still saves code-size and doesn't hurt front-end throughput.

**There is no `test $sign_extended_imm8, r/m32`**, so it saves code-size to use 8-bit operand-size, even though it requires a REX prefix to encode DIL. (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/test)

Since the value of `x` isn't needed after the test, you actually could use `and $imm8, %edi` (3 bytes) to save code-size, but `and`/`jnz` can't macro-fuse on AMD CPUs, or Intel before Sandybridge, so compilers prefer to only write FLAGS.  I suspect nobody's implement the peephole optimization of using `and` instead of `test` with `-mtune=sandybridge` when the register isn't needed later.

```
   0:   f7 c7 02 00 00 00       test   edi,0x2    # imm32 = 2
   6:   40 f6 c7 02             test   dil,0x2    # REX prefix with no bits set
   a:   f6 c7 02                test   bh,0x2     # same byte without REX

   d:   83 e7 02                and    edi,0x2
  10:   40 80 e7 02             and    dil,0x2
  14:   80 e7 02                and    bh,0x2

  17:   0f ba e7 02             bt     edi,0x2    # can't macro-fuse with JCC
```